# PPV vs Sensitivity

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

I am looking at the equation PPV and Sensitivity

and I got this

```
PPV = TP / (TF+FN)
```

and

```
Sensitivity = TP / (TF+FN)
```

Which means both are the same !!

So do we have them in 2 names?

and how come F1 Score is

```
F1 Score = 2*PPV*S / (PPV+S)
```

Can we rewrite F1 Score to be

```
F1 Score = 2*PPV*PPV / (PPV+PPV) = 2*PPV*PPV / (2*PPV) = PPV !!
```

They all the same?

It seems there is some condition or something I am missing here!

can someone please explain to me what am I missing?

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence arguably off-topic here; better suited for [Corss Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using medical diagnosis as an example:
***sensitivity*** is the proportion testing positive among all those who actually have the disease.

**Sensitivity = TP/(TP+FN) = TPR**

While,
***PPV*** is how likely a patient has a predicted specific disease given the test results.

**PPV = TP/(TP+FP)** which is definitely **NOT** equal to **TP/(TP+FN)**!

Regarding F1:
***F1*** is the harmonic mean of *precision* and *sensitivity*. One is normalized by column and the other normalized by row. *Precision* is synonymous with *PPV* while *sensitivity* is synonymous with *TPR*.

**F1 = 2*PPV*TPR / (PPV+TPR)**

Comment: I was looking at this paper arxiv.org/pdf/1703.08705 and it says PPV = TP / (TF+FN) in page 7